# Using a SELECT TABLE.COLUMN, CURSOR(SELECT OTHER_STUFF) in iReport

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, jasper-reports, ireport

I am tasked with moving some existing PL/SQL queries into Jasper Server by making some rudimentary JasperReports. So far this has been straightforward, but I have come across a query that has the following structure and do not know how to use the iReport `$P{ORACLE_REF_CURSOR}` parameter to access the resulting dataset:

`SELECT part.part_name, cursor(SELECT other_stuff...) FROM tbl_part part`

When I copy+paste it into the fields reader, it "correctly" identifies my fields as follows:

1. `java.lang.String` part_name
2. `OracleResultSet` cursor(...)

I would like to know how to fetch the goodies inside of the `cursor()` for each `part_name`.

Comment: Have you tried using `BULK COLLECT INTO`? You can collect the cursor contents into a varray, nested table or an associated array and then use it in a query to join with tables also.